# Postgresql database size is less after migration from oracle

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g, migration, ora2pg

I have migrated Oracle to Postgresql using Ora2pg tool.
The database size before migration in Oracle is around 2Tb,
The same database after migration into Postgresql,size seems only 600 gb.
NOTE: Records are migrated correctly with equal row counts.

Also i wanted to know how Postgresql handles Bytea data type after migration from Blob in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if all migrated objects are present.

However, this is not surprising, and there are several things that can contribute to that:

- You counted the size of the tablespaces in Oracle, but they were partly empty.
- Your table and index blocks were fragmented, while they are not in the newly imported PostgreSQL database.
- Depending on which options you installed in Oracle, the data dictionary can be quite large (though that alone cannot explain the observed difference).

Comment: Is it such that indexes in Oracle consumes lot of space because they have been in oracle from quite long and same indexes consumes less space as they have been imported newly in postgresql. @Laurenz

Comment: Certainly. The same holds for tables.

Comment: What if tables in oracle and Postgresql has same number of rows .

Comment: The number of rows should be the same, right? The difference is that when the table changes, it will become fragmented: deleted rows leave holes, and updated rows may leave holes but also lead to *chained rows*.